# I'm getting Thread [main] (Suspended (entry into method <init> in Game)) and I can't find the error anywhere

Tags: java

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (entry into method <init> in Game))    
Game.<init>() line: 36  
Game.main(String[]) line: 134
```

I keep receiving this error for some reason and I can't figure it out. all help appreciated

It says that there is some sort of error with the public Game() { and the new Game().start(); and I just can't find it

Here's my Game file:

```
package ca.vanzeben.game;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Canvas;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    import ca.vanzeben.game.gfx.Screen;
    import ca.vanzeben.game.gfx.SpriteSheet;

    public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final int WIDTH = 160;
public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH /12*9;
public static final int SCALE = 3;
public static final String NAME = "Wake Me Up...";

private JFrame frame;

public boolean running = false;
public int tickCount = 0;

private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT,                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

private Screen screen;

public Game() {
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));

    frame = new JFrame(NAME);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public void init() {
    screen = new Screen(WIDTH,HEIGHT, new SpriteSheet("/SpriteSheet.png"));
}

public synchronized void start() {
    running = true;
    new Thread(this).start();

}

public synchronized void stop() {
    running = false;
}

public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double nsPerTick = 1000000000D / 60D;

    int frames = 0;
    int ticks = 0;

    long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double delta = 0;

    init();

    while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime)/nsPerTick;
        lastTime = now;
        boolean ShouldRender = true;

        while (delta >= 1) {
        ticks++;
        tick();
        delta -= 1;
        ShouldRender = true;
   }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (ShouldRender) {
        frames++;
        render();
        }

        if (System.currentTimeMillis()- lastTimer >= 1000){
            lastTimer += 1000;
            System.out.println(ticks+ "," +frames);
            frames = 0;
            ticks = 0;
        }
    }
}

public void tick() {
tickCount++;    

for (int i = 0; i <pixels.length; i++) {
pixels[i] = i + tickCount;
}
}

public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    screen.render(pixels, 0, WIDTH);

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(),null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

     public static void main(String[] args){ 
    new Game().start();
    }
```

As I said, all help appreciated. It keeps saying that there's an error and I can't find it

Comment: From the "error message" it seems you don't have an error, but a **breakpoint**. Which IDE are you using, Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You are using **Eclipse**, right?

You don't have an error, just a *method entry breakpoint*. Check the **left** bar beside the code. There will be a blue circle, with a tick and an arrow.

You have multiple options:

- Double click that, it should go away (and restart execution, of course)
- Right click, toggle: breakpoint goes away
- Right click, disable: the breakpoint will be there, but not active
- Instead of **Debug** (the green buggy button), use **Run** (green play button) -- breakpoints stay where they are, but not taken into acccount
- pressing **F8**: breakpoints stay where they are, execution continues until next breakpoint

Comment: Alternatively, use Window->Show view->Other->(find Breakpoints), then Ok ☑. In the Breakpoints view use the double X to delete all breakponts.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like an error. You are running your application inside a debugger or similar development tool which seems to be instructed to suspend your program at the specified location either by a breakpoint or a rule like “stop at instance creation”.

You should check your environment. Running with a plain `java` launcher does not produce such an error.