# Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ZipException))

Tags: java, maven

I am using apache spark. I am getting the following exception when i try to debug the application. There are no errors in the project. I am trying to run a simple wordcount application.

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ZipException))  
    owns: JarFile  (id=32)  
    owns: URLClassPath  (id=33) 
    owns: Object  (id=34)   
    ZipFile.read(long, long, long, byte[], int, int) line: not available [native method]    
    ZipFile.access$1400(long, long, long, byte[], int, int) line: not available 
    ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: not available   
    ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill() line: not available   
    ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream(InflaterInputStream).read(byte[], int, int) line: not available  
    IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, int, boolean) line: not available    
    JarFile.getBytes(ZipEntry) line: not available  
    JarFile.checkForSpecialAttributes() line: not available 
    JarFile.hasClassPathAttribute() line: not available 
    JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.jarFileHasClassPathAttribute(JarFile) line: not available 
    URLClassPath$JarLoader.getClassPath() line: not available   
    URLClassPath.getLoader(int) line: not available 
    URLClassPath.getNextLoader(int[], int) line: not available  
    URLClassPath.getResource(String, boolean) line: not available   
    URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available  
    URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available  
    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>,    AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]    
    Launcher$AppClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: not available   
    Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
    Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available  
    Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: not available  
    LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(boolean, int, String) line: not available
```

Here is the code snippet..

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new   SparkConf().setAppName("JavaSparkSQL").setMaster("local");   
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
// SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(ctx);
JavaRDD<String> lines = ctx.textFile("file.txt");
JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
public Iterable<String> call(String s) {
     System.out.println("hello");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")));
return Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));
}
});
```

Comment: That code snippet does not appear to be called in the stack trace ...

Comment: It is called, when i print the "hello" keyword after the SparkConf line, it prints hello and then code gives exception.

Comment: Yes.  But it is not called anywhere on the stacktrace that you have shown us!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this Q&A:

- [I'm getting Thread [main] (Suspended (entry into method <init> in Game)) and I can't find the error anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120166/im-getting-thread-main-suspended-entry-into-method-init-in-game-and-i-c)

... it looks like you have / Eclipse has set a breakpoint on something to do with throwing a `ZipException`, and that breakpoint has been triggered.  Also, it appears to have been triggered before your application's "main" class was loaded.